# MySql Match Against text + joined variable

Tags: php, mysql, match, match-against

I have tried this `'[#',h.id,']'` AND `'[#'+h.id+']'` 
AND `CONCAT('[#',h.id,']')` . 
             It's not working

I want to select `#+id` from table, this is the code

```
...   MATCH (text) AGAINST ('[#',h.id,']'  IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Thanks.

Comment: what error you got while executing this query ?

Comment: undefined 'h.id', it should be something like '[#\h.id\]'

Comment: Can you write full query and db structure too ?

Comment: It's a 'syntax error', I need to know how to combine text and id.

Comment: are you looking for CONCAT('# ', h.id) function otherwise provide your full query with table structure too